# Add XPath to chrome extension or into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, google-chrome-extension

I'm making chrome extension and i need to have xpath in it, it dose not work even when i add jquery in to the manifest.

ERROR: `Uncaught ReferenceError: $x is not defined`

MANIFEST:

```
"permissions": [
"activeTab",
"*://www.znamky.zsunesco.cz/*"
],
"content_scripts": [
  {
    "matches": ["http://znamky.zsunesco.cz/*"],
    "js": ["jquery-1.11.3.min.js", "Script.js"]
  }
]
```

SCRIPT:

```
$x("//div[@class='nazevprdiv' and ./a[text()='"+name+"']]/../../td/table/tbody/tr[@class='detznamka']/td");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like adelphus said, it's only a variable usd by Firebug as an xpath shortcut. You can implement it with this code:

```
function $x(path){
 var xpath = document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);
   var temp = [];
   for (var i = xpath.snapshotLength - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
     temp.push(xpath.snapshotItem(i));
   }
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`$x` is just a normal Javascript variable name - it's not some special xpath accessor.

It appears that [Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) uses `$x` as an [xpath shortcut](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/$x), but this is not standard.

As the documentation indicates, you should just use [document.evaluate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) which is standard across many browsers (except IE, of course).

**Edit**

As @Xan indicates, `$x` is also used by Chrome as part of their [Command Line API](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/javascript/command-line/command-line-reference).

Comment: For Chrome, it's part of the [console API](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console-api) - so it works from the console, but not from scripts.

Comment: Is there a way to make $x normal function wich would return an array of html elements like $x does? (I've looked at their source code (firebug's) and i found the function and other but there is a lot of othe scripts which are being imported to the script with xpath function: https://github.com/firebug/firebug/tree/master/extension/content/firebug/lib
and https://github.com/firebug/firebug/blob/master/extension/content/firebug/lib/xpath.js